# LG G R watch doesn't sync contacts

Tags: android-wear

I got my LG G R watch the other day. I set it up, it connects to my phone, etc. I installed apps to it fine. However, my contacts aren't syncing when I swipe to the left twice (I'm on the middle tab)

I have M8 on Verizon with root and VenomRoms installed.